# Knockout mapping wcf

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a problem to map my json object returned by a WCF. wcf return a list of PaidPeople class, and jSon return look like

```
[Object { __type="PaidPeople:#model", Amount=110, Attendee=1, more...},  more...]
```

I also JSON.stringify the return object and i get an array of

```
[
{"__type":"PaidPeople:#model","Amount":110,"Attendee":1,"CashPay":1,"DtPaid":"/Date(1338102000000-0700)/","Name":"John Doe"}, more
]
```

my problem is mapping it to my view

here is the code

```
  var PayinyVM = {};

    $.getJSON('/service/PaidService.svc/PaidList', function (data) {
        var tmp = JSON.stringify(data.d);

        PayinyVM.model = ko.mapping.fromJSON(tmp);
        ko.applyBindings(PayinyVM);
    }); //getJSON
```

and HTML is looking like:

```
   <div data-bind="foreach: ????">
        <h3 data-bind="text: Name">
        </h3>
        <p>
            Name: <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

I just started coding with knockout after long time jquery code, and really like it, but I miss a lot of practice. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use following code (`model` instead of `????`):

```
<div data-bind="foreach: model">
    <h3 data-bind="text: Name">
    </h3>
    <p>
        Name: <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much I did try PayinyVM.model before, but couldn't see your solution. Thanks again